# Formula for one cell containing letter "T" and another cell in the same row containing "*T-T*"

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to write a formula that is counting the number of times in which

(1)I have rows with cells in one column  having their content equal to the string "T" and

(2) cells within the same row with their text containing "T-T"(there could be something else before or after T-T).

Here is the formula I am using which is not working:

```
   =COUNTIFS($BI$2:$BO$6016,"*T-T*", $BG$2:$BG$6016,"T")
```

I am searching for "*T-T*" in columns BI through BO and I am searching for "T" only in column BG and I want both of them to coincide in the same row

Comment: You want to count the instance of `T` and `T-T` both.. right? or just where both of them coincides?

Comment: I want both of them ,to coincide in the same row

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($BI$2:$BI$6016, "*T-T*", $BO$2:$BO$6016, "*T-T*" , $BG$2:$BG$6016, "T")` -- Try this

Comment: It give me 0 which is wrong I have rows in which both of them occur

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($BI$2:$BI$6016, "*T-T*", $BG$2:$BG$6016, "T") + COUNTIFS($BO$2:$BO$6016, "*T-T*" , $BG$2:$BG$6016, "T")` @larasmith this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `SUMPRODUCT` like below.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("T-T",$BI$2:$BO$6016,1))*($BG$2:$BG$6016="T"))`

Comment: I wanna coutn occurrences of those cell contents in the same row so I don't think this formula works

Comment: @larasmith, Have you tested this formula? What is the expected result and what is it returning?